# Save row # to list when conditions are met

Tags: c#

I have a datatable imported from a csv. What I'm trying to do is compare all of the rows to each other to find duplicates. In the case of duplicates I am going to add the row # to a list, then write the list to an array and deal with the duplicates after that.

```
            //find duplicate rows and merge them.
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                //loop again to compare rows
                foreach (DataRow dx in dt.Rows)
                {
                   if (dx[0]==dr[0] && dx[1]==dr[1] && dx[2] == dr[2] && dx[3] == dr[3] && dx[4] == dr[4] && dx[5] == dr[5] && dx[7] == dr[7])
                    {
                        dupeRows.Add(dx.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
```

for testing I have added:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(dupeRows.ToArray());
```

which simply outputs System.Data.DataRow.

How do I store the duplicate row index ids?

Comment: This is really inefficient, by the way. Building a dictionary would be much more effective

Comment: If you want to go by Index, use a `for(int i=0;...` loop, instead of foreach.
That's better to avoid two-way compare anyway, now you compare x with y and y with x, and you do not test on ReferenceEquals(x, y). So there are a lot of things coming up.

Comment: My suggestions would be to NOT read a CSV into a datatable if possible, and instead read it into a strongly typed class instead.  Don't reinvent the wheel, and use a prebuilt library like https://www.filehelpers.net/ .  Then you can easily use LINQ to detect duplicates (or eliminate them via .Distinct).

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you saved a string describing the type of the row (what DataRow.ToString() returns by default) at the time you decided the row was a duplicate

Assuming you've read your CSV straight in with some library/driver rather than line by line (which would have been a good time to dedupe) let's use a dictionary to dedupe:

```
Dictionary<string, DataRow> d = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>();

foreach(var ro in dataTable.Rows){
  //form a key for the dictionary
  string key = string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{7}", ro.ItemArray);

  d[key] = ro;
}
```

That's it; at the end of this operation the `d.Values` will be a deduped collection of DataRow. 1000 rows will require 1000 operations so this will likely be orders of magnitude faster than comparing every row to every other row, which would need a million operations for a thousand rows

I've used tabs to separate the values when I formed the key - assuming your data contains no tabs. Best reliability will be achieved if you use a character that does not appear in the data

If you've read your CSV line by line and done a manual string split on comma (i.e. a primitive way of reading a CSV) you could do this operation then instead; after you split you have an array that can be used in place of ro.ItemArray. Process the entire file, creating rows (and adding to the dictionary) only if `d.ContainsKey` returns false. If the dictionary already contains that row, skip on rather than creating a row

Answer (score 0):

The output (System.Data.DataRow) that you are seeing is expected since there is no custom implementation of DataRow.ToString() found in your project,  framework is calling base class's (which is System.Object) [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)() for which the default implementation returns data type of object which invokes that method.

I see three solutions here:

- If possible, try to read the DataTable into custom objects (like
  MyDataTable, MyDataRow) so, you can create your own ToString() like
  below:

> ```
> public class MyDataRow
> {
>     public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return "This is my custom data row formatted string";
>     }
> }
> ```

- in the for loop, when you found duplicated row, either just add
  index/id (sort of primary key) of dx to array and then have another
  for loop to retrieve dupes.
- Third is same as mentioned by Caius Jard.